# Error in PHP soap client to .NET soap Server

Tags: php, soap

PHP soap client in attempting to interact with a .NET soap server results in the following error:
[soap:Receiver] Server was unable to process request. ---> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array.

```
$credentials = array(
    'RequestorUID'=> 'xxxx',
    'RequestorPassword'=> 'xxxx'
);
$param = array('pmPropertyManagerID'=>'xxxx');
$client->GetPropertyStatus($credentials, $param);
```

GetPropertyStatus take two arguments, a credentials object -> which works correctly as other functions that only require credentials are executed correctly. The second argument is defineds as a string and I have attempted to input it directly as a string and base64_encoded string (error: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid), an array and an associative array both string and base64_encoded string and get the error above.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what php client are you using (if any) to generate your base class?

Comment: the default SOAP class.  I know its not custom or NuSOAP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your response, I eventually go it to work doing the following:

```
$client->GetPropertyStatus($credentials, new SoapVar('xxxx', XSD_STRING, 'xsd:string'))
```

I just compare the `$client->__getLastRequest()` to the definitions on wsdl as a small deviation from it would cause an exception